# group_by using value from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using ROR 2.3.8

I have this in `cities_controller.rb`:

```
@shops = Shop.published.search params[:keyword], {
      :conditions     => conditions,
      :star           => true,
      :group_by       => 'city_id',
      :group_function => :attr,
      :page           => params[:page]
    }.merge(:order => 'rating_average DESC')
@cities = @shops.collect { |shop| shopy.city }
```

How can I tell Rails to get the `rating_average` from City model instead of Shop model? Because the Shop model does not have `rating_average`. It's actually `City` model that gets rated.

Thank you.

**UPDATES**

`published` namescope in `Shop.rb`

```
 sphinx_scope(:published) { 
  {:conditions => {:status => 'published'}}
}
```

Indexes in `Shop.rb`

```
  define_index do
    indexes city.name, :as => :name, :sortable => true
    indexes city.duration, :as => :duration
    indexes city.status, :as => :status
    #has city.budget, :as => :budget
    #has city(:created_at), :as => :created_at
    has city(:rating_average), :as => :rating_average
    has city_id
  end
```

**UPDATES 2**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops, :dependent => :destroy    
  ...
end
```

Comment: Should indeed work with joins and then add cities. before rating_average.  But your associations have to be right. Can you show what association to City you have defined in the Shop model.

Comment: @Michael Torfs, please see update.

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins to acheive this:

```
@shops = Shop.published.search params[:keyword], {
      :conditions     => conditions,
      :star           => true,
      :group_by       => :city_id,
      :group_function => :attr,
      :page           => params[:page]
    }.merge(:order => :rating_average,
            :sort_mode => :desc)
```

You should also add `cities.` or `shops.` before columns to specify which table's column.

Comment: Please see updates. I don't think that's the problem, because I have removed `published`, and still can't yield results.

Comment: is `rating_average` a column in `cities` table or a method in `City` model?

Comment: Wait, lemme rebuild my indexes first. I will update again. :P

Comment: I didn't change the `:order`, but just the `shops.city_id` but it returns no result. `rating_average` is a column in `City` model.

Comment: I dont know about sphinx, but try this: `Shop.all :joins => :city, :order => "cities.rating_average DESC"`. Are you getting results?

Comment: I am getting results, but it breaks my view. I tested in console, it gives me all individual not-joined results.

Comment: After looking through sphinx, I updated my answer. I dont know if it works, but give it a try.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but the `rating_average` is still read from Shop instead of City.

Comment: have you tried changing `has city(:rating_average), :as => :city_rating_average` and calling `:order => :city_rating_average`?

Comment: There's result, but not sort accordingly. Again, I think it's referring to `Shop.rating_average`, unless we could use `cities.rating_average` like you mentioned.